# Should I exclude my 'noindex, nofollow, noarchive' pages from my sitemap.xml?

Tags: html, seo, sitemap

I have some legal pages on my website that I exclude with `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noarchive">`. The main goal is that these pages don't show up in search engines. Do I need to exclude it from my sitemap.xml or will the meta tags be sufficient. If not, why would I need to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sitemap is used by search engines to discover your content, so adding content **you do not want** to be indexed is not really useful.

[This documentation page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184) outlines when a sitemap is useful:

> A sitemap is a file where you can list the web pages of your site to
>   tell Google and other search engines about the organization of your
>   site content.  Search engine web crawlers like Googlebot read this
>   file  to more intelligently crawl your site.